# An app keeps sending me to a website i dont want to be sent on

Tags: applications

When i installed an app after a few days it started opening chrome on random time intervals that keep sending me to baovendt.org
How to fix it?

Comment: Deinstall the app?

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to uninstall the app, here's how:

1. Open Settings
2. Find "Apps and notifications"
3. Select "See all (how many apps you have) apps"
4. Locate the app and tap on it
5. Tap on "Uninstall"
6. A dialogue will pop-up, now press "OK" to finish the uninstallation.